# How to access dict inside list

Tags: python, list, api, dictionary

I searched for similar questions with no luck.
I am trying to get the data inside a, under 'bids' and 'asks'.
Here is the code:

```
response = requests.get(book_url, params={'instrument_name': 'BTC_USDT', 'depth': 2})
resp = response.json()
print('resp: ', type(resp))
a  = resp['result']['data']
```

This is what a looks like:

```
[{'bids': [['17015.36', '1.86922', '6'], ['17014.91', '0.01175', '1']],
  'asks': [['17015.37', '0.98410', '3'], ['17015.54', '0.01469', '1']],
  't': 1670869985838}]
```

If I try getting 'bids' I get the following error:

```
a['bids']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[102], line 1
----> 1 a['bids']

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The variable `a` holds a list, so you have to do something like this: `a[0]['bids']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a `list` with one element which is the `dict` you want.

`a['bids']` is asking for a *dict* element with a key of `'bids'`.

Try `a[0]['bids']`.

Comment: That was dumb of me...Thank you for helping. It does work!

Answer (score 0):

The variable *a* is a list. In your example it contains just one element. Considering that it might contain multiple elements you could print them as follows:

```
print(*[_a.get('bids') for _a in a], sep='\n')
```

For the data shown this gives:

```
[['17015.36', '1.86922', '6'], ['17014.91', '0.01175', '1']]
```